# remove(int index) LinkedList Self-Implementation

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to learn performance of LinkedList in comparison to ArrayList
I have made my removal method as follows

Data In the LinkedList, which is being removed is about 1million elements.
My Problem, After Removing All Items: This is the Time Recd.
If I Use Java LinkedList remove(int index) Time: 2000 nanoseconds
If I Use my Custom remove(int index)       Time: 34407000 nanoseconds

Could someone please look at my code and tell me where I am going wrong. I am actually suppose to remove the data by index positions, since the comparison I am trying to attain are by index positions for ArrayList.

```
public Object remove(int index)
{
    checkElementIndex(index);
    return unlink(getNode(index));
}

private Object unlink(ListNode node)
{
    final Object element = node.item;
    final ListNode next = node.next;
    final ListNode prev = node.prev;

    if (prev == null)
    {
        first = next;
    } else
    {
        prev.next = next;
        node.prev = null;
    }

    if (next == null)
    {
        last = prev;
    } else
    {
        next.prev = prev;
        node.next = null;
    }

    node.item = null;
    size--;
    return element;
}

private ListNode getNode(int index)
{
    if (index < (size >> 1))
    {
        ListNode node = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            node = node.next;
        }
        return node;
    } else
    {
        ListNode node = last;
        for (int i = size - 1; i > index; i--)
        {
            node = node.prev;
        }
        return node;
    }
}

private void checkElementIndex(int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= size)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: " + index + ", Size: " + size);
    }
}

    // BOTH THE LIST CONTAIN 1million items.

    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = linkedList.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        linkedList.remove(i);
    }
    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    duration = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("LinkedList Removal Time:  " + duration);

    // This is the Java Collection LinkedList
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = linkedList.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        javaLinkedList.remove(i);

    }
    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    duration = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("My Removal Time:  " + duration);
```

I appreciate, each and every possible suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: A good way to figure this out yourself is by using a profiler such as VisualVM.

Comment: can you post the implementation of checkElementIndex ?

Comment: Hmmm... This code is pretty much an exact replica of Java's `LinkedList` implementation, which means that it's likely that these methods are not the problem.

Comment: @Kakarot I added the checkElementIndex in the above code.

Comment: @user3580294 It is pretty much. But I have some other methods, which are not connected to this methods, but still a large difference of time which I am unable to understand.

Comment: Your code is close enough to the Java version of `LinkedList` that I would guess that these methods are not the problem, unless I missed something. Try a profiler. Also, how are you timing your code?

Comment: @user3580294 System.nanoTime() on both myLinkedList and Java Collection. I am not aware how to use profiler. (NewBie :( Sorry). Each method starts and ends with startTime and endTime and the difference is the duration.

Comment: What happens if you reverse the positions of java's linked list and your linked list?

Comment: Also, do you know how to use a profiler?

Comment: @user3580294 Reverse: How would I do that. Java Collection LinkedList is concrete class, I would not be able to run my method on it, unless I extend them in some way? (I could be wrong?)

Comment: I mean run the Java linked list in the first loop, and your implementation in the second.

Comment: @user3580294 I just did that.
JavaLinkedList Removal Time:  37232000 nanoseconds (This increased?)
My LinkedList Removal Time:  36427000 nanoseconds

Comment: Ah, there we go. First, read [how to microbenchmark in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java). Again, I'd *highly* recommend profiling your code with something like [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/). To be honest, this code looks fine, and I can't tell what's going on.

Comment: I'm sorry that I couldn't spot anything obvious, but I'm curious as to what's going on now...

Comment: @user3580294 So I should try to do a warm up?. Well I am not aware of it and How it works. I am reading the article you mentioned in comment and it does make sense.
  I would try to understand and see if I can manage anything too. This is affecting my compare-perfomace of ArrayList and LinkedList deeply.

Comment: Again, the first thing I would do is actually profile your code. Microbenchmarks are quite difficult to get right, and in my opinion profiling is a much more efficient way of seeing where your bottlenecks are, especially since the profiler will also tell you what method you spend the most time in. If you want to try profiling I'd be happy to guide you through the process. If you're set on microbenchmarks, I'd follow the advice in that article pretty closely, but as I'm sure you're read there are a lot of details that you need to get right if you want to have useful results.

Comment: @user3580294 I think profiling would be a good idea. Could you help me on that plea? ( IT is very kind of you to assist me, thank you).

Comment: I'm moving to the answer section for more space.

Answer (score 0):

(continued from comments)

No problem! First step is to download a profiler (I use [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/). There are other ones out there, but unfortunately I'm not familiar with them...) Once that's downloaded, go ahead fire that up.

The next step is figuring out how to attach the profiler to your process. Once you start up VisualVM, you should see a list of running Java programs on the right. You can ignore that for now. The trick is that you'll need a long-running program to have enough time to attach the profiler to the process. For something like your code, an easier way would be to use `Scanner.nextLine()` to block the program in between loops, sort of like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.nextLine(); // This stops the program and waits for user input.
                    // This will give us all the time in the world to attach the profiler.

// Your code
for (int i = linkedList.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    linkedList.remove(i);
}

scanner.nextLine(); // Same thing here
for (int i = linkedList.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    javaLinkedList.remove(i);
}
```

Now, go ahead start your program. If you go back to VisualVM, you should be able to see your program!

Now double-click on your program. You should see a few messages appear in the console in your program, and the view in VisualVM should change. Go to the "Sampler" tab, click "CPU", then go back to your program and hit enter.

What you see should be pretty self-explanatory. On the left are fully qualified method names with package + class, and a bar representing the portion of CPU time that methods use. Use that to identify where your program is spending all its time. And there you go! If you need more time to profile, just add more elements to the linked lists.

Just a word of caution though; profiling *can* be deceiving, because if another method is messing up your linked list structure it can make a perfectly good method work far harder than it has to. For example, I had to implement `HashMap` as part of a school assignment. When I profiled I noticed that the code to look in buckets was taking up 97%+ of CPU time, even though there was nothing wrong with it. Turns out that a test to get a proper bucket had `>>` instead of `<<`, turning the `HashMap` into a `LinkedList` instead! So while profiling is a good start (and usually is the only thing you need to do to identify problems), just keep in mind that the errors could be elsewhere.

I hope that this helped!

Comment: I just read and it does make a lot of sense. I am just downloading the VisualVM, and going to attach the same as you are saying.
I am sure it will be much more better. It sure will give me some detail about my methods and my future projects. It was weird that the code runs faster after a warm up or initialization of the same code (either through Java or MyCode for LinkedList).

Comment: It's actually not that strange at all. Java has what's called a just-in-time compiler (JIT compiler) that monitors the code you run. If it detects some "hot" code (code that takes up a lot of CPU time or is run frequently), it recompiles the Java bytecode down to native code. This almost always results in speedups compared to Java bytecode. The reasoning behind a warmup period was to get the JVM to recompile all the code you wanted to test, removing the when-is-the-JIT-going-to-activate factor from the benchmark.

Comment: I think I should keep this in mind, when I will be making future projects and try to use the handy feature. I will see if my code speeds up anyway :-/.

Comment: Profilers are invaluable if performance is something you're interested in. There are a few other features of VisualVM that are useful, such as heap/memory usage, if you're worried about excessive object creation.

Comment: I am learning those things and they will be definitely invaluable to me and I shall be thankful to you, every time I use it. :)